# css drop down menu disappears behind content

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

On this page http://www.futureworkinstitute.com/2013/ I'm using the drop down menu from here http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery/ but as you can see, the menu disappears as soon as it leaves the #navbar div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have `overflow` set to `hidden` on your `navbar`:

```css
#navbar {
    ...
    overflow: hidden; //remove this line
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your jQuery might be the trouble. The hover out is setting visibility to hidden on the first UL child element of your main menu items. Try removing this hover out and see if your menu stays put?

```
$(" #nav li").hover(function(){
$(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show(400);
},function(){
$(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```